# Trusted root certificate on azure app services

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I have an asp.net mvc app that needs to access a backend api and several services that is using **self signed certs**. Have no control over forcing client to use proper certs.

On my development environment, i am installing the self signed certs on Trusted Root Certificates to have it work.

However, I am facing SSL certification error when connecting to those services after publishing the asp.net mvc app to **azure app services** but I am unable to find a way to overcome this.

Is there any way that I can overcome this challenge like installing self sign cert on azure app services? I would not like to ignore ssl error in code level if possible as this would require changes on multiple part in code.

**Limitation**:

1. Production Backend API and other services provided by client is **using self signed cert**
2. The asp.net mvc app **must be hosted on azure app services** provided by client

Answer (score 1):

Answering based on your requirements that you only need to connect to a private endpoint that has a private cert (your app service can have a public endpoint).

Try to follow the guide outlined here to first upload the private certificate chain: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate#upload-a-private-certificate (make sure to include the whole chain).

Once you upload the private cert, follow this guide to access it from your code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate-in-code

From there you should be able to use the certificate as needed within your code.